# Issue with GRASS tool r.to.vector

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, vector

I'm trying to obtain quality vector data from a JPEG raster file of a cadastre area in the Netherlands. I thinned the raster with the GRASS thin tool and also filled it with the fill tool, but when I run the algorithm the program either crashes or gives me an error.
I'm using the GRASS tool provided with the QGI 3.20.2 version.

What could be the problem?
In the log there is a warning, but I don't understand to what it refers to.
[image: log of the algorithm once the program crashes]

Comment: Please add ASCII streams of data as text, not an image.

Comment: The warning is not relevant here. Can you make the mapset available for inspection?